# Is there any way to know that an android app is exiting?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want following behavior in my app:

1) Show **notification on its launch**: done

2) **Do not show notification while switching through activities** of the app

3) If another app is launched over this app, while **coming back to the app again show notification**.

I am planning to implement it via shared prefs(by storing a boolean value in it),

But cannot figure out the place to reset this value

i.e. how to know that app is exiting or switching to another app to reset this value(so it can show notification when app is launched again).

Comment: Read android lifecycle. You can put your notification code in onResume() method in activity.

Comment: officebrain: showing notification has been achieved(see point#1). What i want is to figure out place to set/reset bool which decides showing notification in APP(not activity) with above given conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect if all application's activities gone to background you need to extend Application class and register activity lifecycle listeners. Then just count calls to onPause() and onCreate() method.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)

Answer (score 1):

When an `Activity` goes to the background, `onPause()` is called, when it comes back to the foreground, `onResume()` is called. You can use that states to hide/show your notifications or even store your `SharedPreferences`.

Have a look at the Activity Lifecylce:

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Comment: i need to handle notification in scope of APP not activity, i.e. if any of the activity(of APP) as shown notification, it should not be shown by another activity of that APP but at the same time, if APP(not activity) goes in background & then is relaunched, activity which comes on foreground should show notification. So, I think it cannot be managed with activity lifecyle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand Android application life cycle.

Go through the following methods documentation.

```
onCreate() , onStart(), onPause() , onResume() , onDestroy() , onRestart()
```

[Link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> 3) If another app is launched over this app, while coming back to the
>   app again show notification again.

To do this you need to overwrite back button and check activity stack. If it is 0 - show notification.